Powerautomate Get User Profile by "Job Title"
I'm trying to get user profile by the "job title". For example i need to get the users who are under "HR Coordinator" and "Recruitment Officer". I know the names of the people under these job titles. But people change. There is a connector "Search for users (V2)" but this connector does not allow to search via job title. So i had to load without any filters which loaded about 446 user profiles and then used couple of loops to filter down to the job title that i'm after. This method uses a lot of processing requests, and we got a warning for executing excessive number of requests. The loops are unnecessarily utilizing processing requests to just hunt down the job title of interest. As you can see from the process mining, have used 3568 requests.
Is there a better method which will take less processing request and less time?



Try using MS graph to list users and use filter query based on jobTitle. Check: List users. Let me know if it works for you.

Following up on the comment @ganesh, how about a call to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(jobTitle,'HR') or something? Maybe this might help as well source:

use of $search
use of $filter with startWith, endsWith, eq etc


An endsWith requires advanced query capabilities: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http#query-scenarios-that-require-advanced-query-capabilities
Don't forget to add the $count parameter to the URI and include the ConsistencyLevel key with eventual value in the headers for this type of request.
